# How to fix audio static

Tags: audio

I have noticed lately that there is some static or feedback when listening to audio on my computer. I regularly stream music and movies, but have only recently noticed the issue. The speakers are not busted on my TV. I put headphones in the front and back of the computer to check and see if I could narrow down the issue. No matter what I listen through (TV, headphones, etc.) I can hear the static. It also doesn't matter where I plug them in. I've tried HDMI, VGA with an aux cable, and headphones. The result is always the same. The static isn't extremely loud, but it is definitely noticeable. I don't have a sound card, just the regular onboard audio. I have a Nvidia GTX 560SE graphics card that the HDMI runs through if that matters. I figure my motherboard is just getting old (about 2 years) but I was wondering if I might be missing something. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the nose loud only when music is playing? Or can you hear it all the time.  Are your graphics, audio and chipset diverge drivers up to date from the manufacturers website

Comment: I only hear it when there is audio playing. It isn't constant even then. It comes and goes. Sometimes it's a half a second, others its ten of fifteen seconds. All drivers are up to date.

Comment: Does it happen via browser only, streaming only? Does an audio CD have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It could be a DPC problem related to a bad driver. Run **[this program](http://www.thesycon.de/deu/latency_check.shtml)** and see whether you have red bars. If yes, check your drivers in Device Manager.

Comment: I get one red or yellow bar every 30 seconds or so. I checked all the drivers it suggested. Network, USB, Webcam, etc. It didn't seem to change. Thanks for your help, though.